# ASP.NET Microsoft CRM Starter kit

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, crm

Can anybody recommend a "starter kit" or basic framework for an asp.net web app that can read data from Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

No updates are required from the app at this time, just reads. I'm currently reading through the SDK documentation but a simplified project would be quite handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sample code (in C# and VB.net) for doing various things with CRM comes with the SDK.

Have a look in the \sdk\server folder and the \sdk\visualstudiotemplates folder in the same folder that you installed the SDK in.  Hopefully these should give you a head start.

Answer (score 0):

As for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Software Development Kit (SDK) the download can be made [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004)

In the /sdk/crmsdk2011.chm document one should find many tutorials that are assisted by code (.sln included)